# What causes Cryptocurrencies to Exhibit Similar Long Term Behaviour?

Tags: trading, investment-strategies, cryptocurrency

I am developing a cryptocurrency pairs trading strategy.

To identify suitable pairs to trade, I looped through thousands of cryptos and tested whether they behaved similarly in the long-run (i.e., cointegration). If they did, I added them to a list.

Due to multiple comparisions, many pairs on this list will be spurious. To filter these out, I want to only keep pairs if I can find strong fundamental reasons to do so.

My question is: What are some examples of fundamental reasons which might cause cryptos to exhibit similar long term behaviour?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: hype train is a bad way of talking about crytpos, because you know where a train is going. They're more like hype sparrows.

Comment: Cryptocurrency questions are off-topic here unless relating directly to personal finance.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know whether to ask here or on Quant Finance SE, but thought it would be criticised for not being about maths?

Comment: @Jack you can easily reword it to pass Chris W. Rea's filter. This is about asset correlations and why things trade similarly, in your "personal account"

Comment: I would say you shouldn't over-analyse this. At the current stage of the market all coins/tokens are correlated to BTC trends which is essentially the market sentiment(even at all time lows, BTC's market cap is 1/3rd of the whole market). The total market cap still being in its infancy(compared to stock market or gold) also doesnt help with volatility. Note,it's not a co-incidence most pairs are BTC pairs with usually only a handful of the major alt-coins having USD(T) pairs available, so if you re trying to reach a strategy over trading I would compare against BTC/USD for the same time frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The majority of the volatility of all crypto currencies is based on FOMO (fear of missing out) and FUD (fear, uncertainty and doubt).
As this affects all of them the same way, every wave of hype, panic, and new customers result in synchronized activities and behavior.

Contrary to shares of any company, there are no underlying values to assess, and no new information about successes can develop, so the hype waives alone drive the prices.